# Magento 2 Email set as Optional on Create Customer Account API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, customer-account

I have created one module that overrides Magento's default create customer account API.
Now, I want to set the email parameter as Optional.

Magento uses the Below API to create a Customer Account.
{{base_url}}/rest/all/V1/customers

Does anyone have a solution on how to fix it?